# How to list docker logs size for all containers?

Tags: docker

If you do `docker container ls --size` it doesn't show the size of the logs, which might be taking all your space and you don't even know.

Answer (score 55):

Here is the command

```
sudo du -h $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $(docker ps -qa))
```

Also a good way to prevent logs from taking all your space is to add this to your docker-compose

```yaml
logging:
  driver: "json-file"
  options:
    max-size: "100m"
    max-file: "5"
```

Comment: I would like to add that we can set a default value for all **new** containers by adding these options into `/etc/docker/daemon.json` 
`{ "log-opts": { "max-size": "20m", "max-file": "3" } }` 
For existing containers the only solution is to recreate it. 

I don't know why it is unlimited by default :( ...

Answer (score 4):

Size of logs for each docker container , sorted by size:

```
# without total:
sudo du -h  $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $(docker ps -qa)) | sort -h

# with total:
sudo du -ch $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $(docker ps -qa)) | sort -h
```

Total size of all docker containers logs in one line:

```
# human-readable:
sudo du -ch $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $(docker ps -qa)) | tail -n1

# in Mbytes (suitable for monitoring scripts):
sudo du -cm $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $(docker ps -qa)) | tail -n1
```

Will cause error if you don't have any docker containers (`docker ps -qa` output is empty).

Comment: In order to minify code, `--format='{{.LogPath}}' ` argument could be changed with `-f '{{.LogPath}}' ` argument (single "minus" with no "equal" character)